# Option Group can't be selected in quasar 2 / Vue 3 when trying to migrate from quasar 1 /vue 2

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am trying to build dynamic option groups. I have found and modified code using old versions to achieve what I think I need. The problem is, when I try to migrate this code to Quasar2/Vue3, I am no longer able to select any of the options, and I am running out of ideas where to look next. Browser console gives no hints what might be going wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!--
    -- https://quasar.dev/start/umd used as a base template
    -- https://codepen.io/cp-tof06/pen/xxGBzKr used for creating radio button groups. This is vue 2, though. 

  -->
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.6.1/dist/quasar.prod.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="q-app">

  <div class="row q-col-gutter-md q-pa-md">
    <q-option-group
      v-for="(data, index) in reviewData" :key="data.id"
      v-model="data.selected"
      :options="data.options"
      color="primary"
    ></q-option-group>
  </div>
  <div> Selected: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.6.1/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
<!-- old versions that work... 
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.9.12/dist/quasar.umd.min.js'></script-->
    <script>
      /* ...when app initialization rows are changed to these 
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data() {  
   */
      const app = Vue.createApp({
        setup () {
  

        return {

        reviewData: [ 
            {
              id: 'group0',
              options: [
                {label: '1', value: 1},
                {label: '2', value: 2},
                {label: '3', value: 3}
              ],
              selected: null
            },
            {
              id: 'group1',
              options: [
                {label: '11',value: 11},
                {label: '12',value: 12},
                {label: '13',value: 13}
              ],
              selected: null
            }
              ]      
            }
        },
      computed: {
    selected() {
      return this.reviewData.reduce((acc, d) => ({ ...acc, [d.id]: d.selected }), {})
    }  
  }
      })

      app.use(Quasar)
      app.mount('#q-app')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would not recommend mixing Composition API and Options API together, unless you are progressively migrating from one to the other. It may confuse you like in this situation. You are returning `reviewData` directly from `setup()`, without making it a `ref`, `reactive`, etc. So, it stays as a static variable, thus clicking the controls don't change anything. You need to make it reactive using [Vue Reactivity APIs](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html).

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const reviewData = ref([
      {
        id: 'group0',
        options: [
          {
            label: '1',
            value: 1
          },
          {
            label: '2',
            value: 2
          },
          {
            label: '3',
            value: 3
          }
        ],
        selected: null
      },
      {
        id: 'group1',
        options: [
          {
            label: '11',
            value: 11
          },
          {
            label: '12',
            value: 12
          },
          {
            label: '13',
            value: 13
          }
        ],
        selected: null
      }
    ])

    const selected = computed(() =>
      reviewData.value.reduce(
        (acc, data) => ({
          ...acc,
          [data.id]: data.selected,
        }),
        {},
      ),
    )

    return {
      reviewData,
      selected
    }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar)
app.mount('#q-app')
```

```html
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="row q-col-gutter-md q-pa-md">
    <q-option-group
      v-for="data in reviewData"
      :key="data.id"
      v-model="data.selected"
      :options="data.options"
      color="primary"
    ></q-option-group>
  </div>
  <div> Selected: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.6.4/dist/quasar.prod.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.6.1/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Composition API, Options API and ref were actually just the keywords I started researching after I posted the question, but could not yet wrap my head around those. Your answer seems to illustrate the usage neatly. A small question, what do you recommend reading to get myself better acquainted with these concepts? Or is it just the documentation and search engines that are my friends here?

Comment: @tjr Vue documentation is really comprehensive and clear about this topic. So, yes, the documentations and search engines are your best friends.